# How to get value from object called George

Tags: javascript

how to get the value of an object with 2 values.
the object is called George and has 2 values, name and age.

Answer (score 1):

You have your object literal

```
var George = {
  name: 'George',
  age: 53,
}
```

You can access its values in 2 ways:

1. The standard approach:

Like in any object oriented language, you can use the point operator to access:

```
console.log(George.age);
var GeorgesName = George.name
```

This should be familiar to you if you have used other languages like Java, Python or anything Object oriented.

2. The dictionary approach:
   But since Objects in JS are also simple dictionaries, you can use the key (age or name) and use the square bracket notation you would use for arrays:

```
console.log(George["age"]);
var GeorgesName = George["name"];
```

The advantage of this approach is, that you can use it even when you do not know, which key and value will be of interest. You can dynamically pass a string with the key ("age" for example) to a function `getObjectValue` and return the value.

3. Other interesting functions:
   You can also iterate over an Object keys or values with a for-in loop or even better, use the `Object.keys(George)` or `Object.values(George)` functions to retrieve an array of `["age","name"]` or `["George",53]`